# Set Size of JFace Wizard

Tags: java, eclipse, wizard, rcp, jface

I am building an Eclipse RCP application and am having trouble on settings the size of a JFace Wizard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that the Wizard is the size of your largest WizardPage.

Comment: Could you please give a code snippet on how to set the height of a wizard page?

Answer (score 10):

Yeah, it is generally a good idea to let Eclipse work out the size for you.  However, if you really want to set the size of the wizard, you can do it by setting the size of the WizardDialog which you are using to open your wizard.  For example:

```
Wizard wizard = new MyCustomWizard();
WizardDialog wizardDialog = new WizardDialog(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell(), wizard);
wizardDialog.setPageSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
// Could also use wizardDialog.setMinimumPageSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT) if that's more appropriate
```

Answer (score 7):

To set the size of the dialog, it's

```
wizardDialog.getShell().setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
```

---

To disable that the dialog is resizable, leave the SWT.RESIZE bit in an own WizardDialog implementation:

```
// original WizardDialog class
public WizardDialog(Shell parentShell, IWizard newWizard) {
    super(parentShell);
    setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.RESIZE);
    setWizard(newWizard);
    ...
}

// Own implementation without SWT.RESIZE
public NoResizeWizardDialog(Shell parentShell, IWizard newWizard) {
    super(parentShell);
    setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    setWizard(newWizard);
    ...
}
```