# How to force a minimum height of a JFace Wizard in Eclipse?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm presenting a wizard (code [here](https://github.com/bioclipse/bioclipse.hpc/blob/master/plugins/net.bioclipse.hpc/src/net/bioclipse/hpc/wizards/ExecuteCommandWizard.java)) that gets too low, so the content does not show completely (see screenshot below):

[image]

How can I force the wizard to have a minimum height?

According to the answer on [this question here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367075/set-size-of-jface-wizard), the wizard will be the same height as the largest wizardpage in the wizard, but my wizard obvilusly does not get resized according to at least the *content* of the largest page, and I also tried to set the minimum height of the first visible wizard page with code like this in the WizardPage class:

```
@Override
public void createControl(Composite parent) {
  // create the composite to hold the widgets
  Composite composite =  new Composite(parent, SWT.NULL);
  composite.setSize(300, 1024); // TODO: Does this work?

  GridData gridData = new GridData(300, 1024);
  gridData.heightHint = 1024;
  gridData.minimumHeight = 1024;
  composite.setLayoutData(gridData);
```

... but without success so far.

Any hints?

Comment: have you tried overriding createPageControls in your wizard (empty block)?

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't help, unfortunately. Btw, note that this is the WizardPage class, not the Wizard class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set

```
parent.setLayout(new GridLayout());
```

to your `createControl()` implementation of your first page.

It appears the parent you get in that method has an instance of `PageContainerFillLayout` as layout, not `GridLayout`.

If you have access to your WizardDialog, you could also call

```
wizardDialog.setMinimumPageSize(300, 1024)
```

Comment: Indeed, the parent.setLayout(new GridLayout()); did the trick! Big thanks!

Comment: Well, the second example worked much better in fact. The first one gave me strange oddities, such as that the content in the second WizardPage got vertically "centered". I had to do some casting though, to get grips of the `WizardDialog` from the `WizardPage`, but it works very well: `((WizardDialog) this.getWizard().getContainer()).setMinimumPageSize(300, 400);`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify a height hint for the GridData.

Alternatively, you could use a three column GridLayout and get all the rows after the first to span columns 2 and 3. I tend to use GridLayout and haven't had this problem before.

Comment: Yeah, as you can see in the code above, I do set a heightHint for the GridData ... but it still does not work. Can't really figure out why ...

Comment: So you did. It's been a long day, I must have missed that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this codes below:

`parent.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {
            public void controlResized(ControlEvent event) {
                parent.setSize(parent.computeSize(490, 320));
            }
        });`

Answer (score 0):

I just had a very similar problem (on Windows): A wizard where the wizard page had no message was not shown completely. What quickly solved it for me was to just add a message with a single space in the wizard page constructor:

```
class Page extends WizardPage {

    Page() {
        super("page.id", "Page title", null);
        setMessage(" ");
```

The accepted answer did not work for me (the wizard has quite some fields).