# How to fix setSize issue with WizardPage?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

Its not duplicate question.
My Problem here, When I ran this page working fine in one system(OS), But if run this same code in other system(OS) widget is not showing fully. Its hiding widgets
I have a WizardPage window.

```
class MyPage extends WizardPage{
}

MyPage page = new MyPage();
page.setSize(400, 630);
```

When I open this page on a different system, I am getting this page partially displaying and hiding below.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force a minimum height of a JFace Wizard in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039821/how-to-force-a-minimum-height-of-a-jface-wizard-in-eclipse). Also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367075/set-size-of-jface-wizard

Comment: No. i tried that way.Its not working.Its hiding the page

Comment: Update the your post with the minimum testable code.

Comment: brother, its working in one system. if I run this code in other system, the page is loading with hiding widgets