# Set the size of eclipse wizard

Tags: eclipse, size, wizard

I tried to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367075/set-size-of-jface-wizard) solution to my problem, but it doesn't work. I've got a class which extends `Wizard` and implements `INewWizard`. It's called by an `Activator`-class. I don't have `wizardDialog` anywhere so I unsuccessfully tried it like this:

```
public SeeTableScreenWizard()
{
    super();
    WizardDialog wizardDialog = new WizardDialog(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell(), this);
    wizardDialog.setPageSize(800, 400);
    setNeedsProgressMonitor(true);
}
```

The reason why i need it is the following: one of the pages has a `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List` which has many entries. Its doesn't have any consequences until i run the wizard for the second time. Its height is being set to the screen height, i suppose because it tries to set the size to that big page created at the first run.

Give me some clues please.

Comment: Set a height hint on the Layout for the List

Comment: wow it was surprisingly simple :)

Comment: @greg-449 is there a possibility to set size for the rows of `Table` widget in the similar way? Right now I'm working with [that](http://pastie.org/9082085) solution, but it is insufficient, because the rows are being resized with quite big delay after the page with table got visible.

Comment: For a TableViewer a label provider based on `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` or `StyledCellLabelProvider` is what I would use - that ends up using a similar measure call. This should not have a delay.

Comment: How do i apply that? Do i need to set a TableViewer for my Table first?

Comment: Yes that is for the TableViewer. I don't actually see why there should be any delay using the SWT.MeasureItem listener directly, that is what OwnerDrawLabelProvider uses internally.

Comment: The Table is created in method `createControl(Composite parent)` which overrides `IDialogPage.createControl(Composite)`. This is where I add the Listener too. But i fill the table with its contents in the method `setVisible`. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Try `Table.setRedraw(false)` before you fill in the table (and set to true again at the end)

Comment: I now realized what really happens for this bug. Not the row height resizing is being delayed, but the positioning of the custom contents in the resized cells. As soon as I open the corresponding wizard screen I see [this](http://i.imgur.com/mGcNbvD.png) picture. After approx. 2 seconds it changes to [this](http://i.imgur.com/z3GuULN.png). Do you have an idea how I could fix it?